# `xml_get_current_column_number` returns "wrong" value

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a simple XML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        test
    </li>
</ul>
```

using the [PHP XML parser functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php).
I'm collecting every element using the two handlers set by calling `xml_set_element_handler`.
In both handlers, I can get the current line number, column number, and byte index, by calling the functions `xml_get_current_line_number`, `xml_get_current_column_number`, `xml_get_current_byte_index`.

However, when parsing the opening tag, the column number and byte index 
do not point to the beginning of the opening tag, but at the end. 
I'm assuming this is because the parser, at that point, has already consumed the opening tag.

For example, for the tag `li` in the example, it will return the column `8` (starting from 1)
for the second line, that is, the character `>`, while I am expecting `5`. Is there a way to accomplish this?